# Getting image coordinates

Tags: android, image

Well, I am having an image and I want to display info when certain areas are being clicked. I am using the event.getX and getY methods. The question is how do I know in my image the coordinates of that area? And how this is related to each screen resolution?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the x and y of the View by using `getLocationOnScreen` of a View.

```
int[] values= new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(values);
int x = values[0];
int y = values[1] ;
```